# Facncybox in Jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, fancybox

I am using jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.js of fancy box in asp.net application

Q1: In the base page I have datagrid and on combobox. On selection of combobox, the datagrid is populated.
From the datagrid I open the fancybox when user click on Edit link. I open new page like

In EditProjectTask.aspx I have the controls in edible mode. Now if user closes the window using default icon provided in fancybox, then if user selects some other option from combobox the url changes into EditProjectTask?Task= 86

Q2: #
From the # datagrid I open the fancybox when user clicks on Edit link. I open new page like

In EditProjectTask.aspx I have the controls in edible mode. Now when user updates the the content, I want to close the fancybox and also refresh the parent window. 
I have achieved this using 
After update i #

But it reloads all the pages. Can I use some Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how you would use fancybox for this but here is a great post explaining [how you edit your gridview's data using jquery dialog](http://xlib.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/asp-net-gridview-edit-records-using-jquery-dialog/)